# Why does Liquibase migration on MySQL database die after acquiring lock on DC/OS (worked fine with docker-compose)?

Tags: docker, liquibase, dcos

- DC/OS 1.9.0
- MARATHON 1.4.2
- LIQUIBASE 3.5.3

I implemented a short lived docker container that runs a Liquibase migration against a mysql database. The container has been working great during development via docker-compose. However, I'm attempting to implement this container within a DCOS cluster in preparation for production.

When Liquibase runs, it successfully acquires a lock and then just dies. Here is the output of the run:

```
DEBUG 4/14/17 8:06 PM: liquibase: Connected to root@10.0.1.113@jdbc:mysql://test-db.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/myapp
DEBUG 4/14/17 8:06 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 4/14/17 8:06 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from myapp.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 4/14/17 8:06 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from myapp.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
INFO 4/14/17 8:06 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
/usr/local/bin/liquibase: line 56:   295 Killed                  java -cp "$CP" $JAVA_OPTS liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ${1+"$@"}
```

The `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table is successfully created so I know it is both accessing the database and creating tables, however it just dies.

After the run, the lock table looks like:

```
MySQL [myapp]> select * from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
+----+--------+-------------+----------+
| ID | LOCKED | LOCKGRANTED | LOCKEDBY |
+----+--------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |        | NULL        | NULL     |
+----+--------+-------------+----------+
```

Here is the command that is being run:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=base_change_log.xml --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --url=jdbc:mysql://test-db.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/myapp --contexts=production --username=root --password=****** --classpath=/opt/jdbc_drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar --logLevel=debug update
```

This is the command the liquibase bash file runs:

```
java -cp .:/opt/liquibase/liquibase.jar:/opt/liquibase/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --changeLogFile=base_change_log.xml --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --url=jdbc:mysql://test-db.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory/myapp --contexts=production --username=root --password=****** --classpath=/opt/jdbc_drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar --logLevel=debug update
```

As I said, this container works fine locally with docker-compose, it also works if I install all deps on one of the dcos slaves and run liquibase locally.

Are there any better ways to debug this? Has anyone successfully run a liquibase migration inside a DCOS cluster?

Comment: You should also show the app definition. Also, check the Mesos logs. I suspect that you specified too little memory, and the container OOMs

Comment: @Tobi you are my hero. I had never thought about an OOM issue, upping it from 128MB did the trick. Thanks so much! Feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Where did you find the OOM? What's the location of the logs? Mind sharing the line with the error? I'd appreciate.

Comment: Normally you can find OOM messages in the Mesos master logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Mesos master logs. I suspect you are encountering a OOM kill of the task.